Cannot set Cookies
Please help me with this. On the backend side, when an user logins, I will set a Cookie and send back to them. But on the frontend side, when I check in applications/cookies, it says

Here's my code:
        ResponseCookie cookie = ResponseCookie.from("refreshToken", refreshToken)
                .httpOnly(true)
                .secure(false)
                .path("/")
                .maxAge(7 * 24 * 60 * 60)
                .sameSite("Strict")
                .build();

        response.addHeader(HttpHeaders.SET_COOKIE, cookie.toString());

And I also set cors filter:
    @Bean
    public CorsFilter corsFilter() {
        UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource source = new UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource();
        CorsConfiguration config = new CorsConfiguration();
        config.addAllowedOrigin("http://localhost:3030");
        config.addAllowedHeader("*");
        config.addAllowedMethod("*");
        config.setAllowCredentials(true);
        source.registerCorsConfiguration("/**", config);
        return new CorsFilter(source);
    }

Here's my call on front end:

And my controller and my service:
@Operation(summary = "Đăng nhập", description = "API để đăng nhập")
    @PostMapping("/login")
    public ApiResponse<LoginRespone> login(
            @Valid
            @RequestBody LoginRequest request,
            HttpServletResponse response
    ){
        return ApiResponse.<LoginRespone>builder()
                .result(authService.login(request, response))
                .build();
    }

public LoginRespone login(LoginRequest request, HttpServletResponse response){

        User user = userRepository.findByEmail(request.getEmail())
                .orElseThrow(() -> new AppException(ErrorCode.NOT_EXISTED));

        if (user.getIsActive() == Status.PENDING){
            userRepository.log_auth("login", user.getUserId(), user.getEmail(), "Fail", "Unverified account");
            throw new AppException(ErrorCode.UNVERIFIED_ACCOUNT);
        }

        if (user.getIsActive() == Status.BANNED){
            userRepository.log_auth("login", user.getUserId(), user.getEmail(), "Fail", "Forbidden account");
            throw new AppException(ErrorCode.FORBIDDEN_ACCOUNT);
        }

        boolean authenticated = passwordEncoder.matches(
                request.getPassword(),
                user.getPassword()
        );

        if (!authenticated) {
            userRepository.log_auth("login", user.getUserId(), user.getEmail(), "Fail", "Wrong password");
            throw new AppException(ErrorCode.UNAUTHENTICATED);
        }

        var accessToken = jwtService.generateAccessToken(user);
        var refreshToken = jwtService.generateRefreshToken(user);

        var storedToken = Token.builder()
                .token(refreshToken)
                .tokenType(TokenType.BEARER)
                .userId(user.getUserId())
                .build();
        tokenRepository.save(storedToken);

        ResponseCookie cookie = ResponseCookie.from("refreshToken", refreshToken)
                .httpOnly(true)
                .secure(false)
                .path("/")
                .maxAge(7 * 24 * 60 * 60)
                .sameSite("Lax")
                .build();

        response.addHeader(HttpHeaders.SET_COOKIE, cookie.toString());

        userRepository.log_auth("login", user.getUserId(), user.getEmail(), "Success", "Login successfully");

        return LoginRespone.builder()
                .accessToken(accessToken)
                .refreshToken(refreshToken)
                .userResponse(userMapper.toUserResponse(user))
                .build();
    }

And my corsFilter:

Please help me with this

Please add the complete controller code so that I also see the path (url) mappings

sorry for keeping you waiting, i have added it

after researching for a bit it seems like there is no way around this issue - you have to set Same-site to none which of course limits you if you try developing on a different domain from your backend (since you can't set secure to true with http). It will work if both backend and frontent are on localhost
